# PHP json_encode as object after PHP array unset()

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm experiencing odd behavior with `json_encode` after removing a numeric array key with `unset`. The following code should make the problem clear. I've run it from both the CLI and as an Apache mod:

**PHP version info:**

```
C:\Users\usr\Desktop>php -v
PHP 5.3.1 (cli) (built: Nov 20 2009 17:26:32)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$a = array(
    new stdclass,
    new stdclass,
    new stdclass
);
$a[0]->abc = '123';
$a[1]->jkl = '234';
$a[2]->nmo = '567';

printf("%s\n", json_encode($a));
unset($a[1]);
printf("%s\n", json_encode($a));
```

**Program Output**

```
C:\Users\usr\Desktop>php test.php
[{"abc":"123"},{"jkl":"234"},{"nmo":"567"}]
{"0":{"abc":"123"},"2":{"nmo":"567"}}
```

As you can see, the first time `$a` is converted to JSON it's encoded as a javascript array. The second time around (after the `unset` call) `$a` is encoded as a javascript object. Why is this and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason for that is that your array has a hole in it: it has the indices 0 and 2, but misses 1. JSON can't encode arrays with holes because the array syntax has no support for indices.

You can encode [`array_values($a)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) instead, which will return a reindexed array.

Comment: Alternatively you can sort the array after unsetting an element.

Comment: @NullUserException Though that will have the side effect of, well, sorting your array.

Comment: For those wondering about the `unset` behavior, view the following link and scroll down to "Useful functions": http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

"The unset() function allows removing keys from an array. Be aware that the array will not be reindexed"

Comment: @NullUserException Great addition! Needed to sort the array anyway - killing two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the `array_values` technique it is possible to use `array_splice` and remove an element and re-index in one step:

```
unset($a[1]);
```

Instead:

```
array_splice($a, 1, 1);
```

Comment: absolutely perfect way to do the job without messing up the collection, thanks!

Comment: This. The most elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option for json_encode, like: `json_encode($a, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` so you will always have the same result.