# Removing JSON children by key in PHP

Tags: php, json

My goal is to have a function that can remove a specified json child, which could also be nested inside deeper.

My function looks like this:

```
private function removeJsonChild(String $jsonKey, String $jsonString)
{
    $json = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $arr_index = array();

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $json[$key] = $this->removeJsonChild($jsonKey, json_encode($value));
        }

        if ($key == $jsonKey) {
            $arr_index[] = $key;
        }
    }

    foreach ($arr_index as $i) {
        unset($json[$i]);
    }

    return json_encode($json);
}
```

The function would work if i wouldn't check if a `$value` is an array and then call the function again recursively. But there is the problem i think. In the statement where i assign the return value of the function to `$json[$key]`. What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**: definitely forgot a `json_decode`. New code looks like this:

```
private function removeJsonChild(String $jsonKey, String $jsonString)
{
    $json = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $arr_index = array();

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $json[$key] = json_decode($this->removeJsonChild($jsonKey, json_encode($value)));
        }

        if ($key == $jsonKey) {
            $arr_index[] = $key;
        }
    }

    foreach ($arr_index as $i) {
        unset($json[$i]);
    }

    return json_encode($json);
}
```

**EDIT2**:

The function works now, however it slightly changes the json schema.

An JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "oyzadsaigny647"
  }
]
```

now becomes this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "oyzadsaigny647"
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, separate the responsibilities here. Write one recursive function that can remove keys from arrays. Then write a second function which cares about the en-/decoding to/from JSON.

Comment: does it work with the json_decode?

Comment: see my last edit

Comment: This looks like a perfect example project to learn TDD - try to write test cases, starting from the simplest one, to cover that requirement. If something along that way is not working out, share your attempts

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3869129/476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private function removeJsonChild(String $jsonKey, String $jsonString) {

   $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

   $data = $this->removeKeyFromArray($key, $data);

   return json_encode($data);

}

private function removeKeyFromArray(String $deleteKey, array $data) {

  unset($data[$deleteKey]); // No need to check if it exists, it just does nothing in that case

  foreach($data as $key => value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $data[$key] = $this->removeKeyFromArray($deleteKey, $value);
    }
  }
  return $data;
}
```

NOTE: this will work in case of dictionaries, i.e. array with actual `keys`. If you have a plain array such as `[1, 10, 23, 15]` the unset behaviour is wrong, as pointed out by @deceze♦

Comment: thank you for your answer. works perfetly fine for such json objects: `{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "oyziasasgny647",
  "status": "active",
  "lastUpdate": "2019-03-08T00:00:00+00:00"
}`
but does not for this: 
`[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "oyziasasgny647",
    "status": "active",
    "lastUpdate": "2019-03-08T00:00:00+00:00"
  }
]`

it isn't deleting the `lastUpdate` key in that case.

Comment: the problem is, i don't exactly know the schema of the json before executing the function.

Comment: There was an overlapping of `$key` variable, my fault. See my edited answer.

Comment: Btw the problem in my `NOTE` comment would only arise if you use a number as the key to remove

Comment: ok thanks. when i try to remove `latestVersion` it doesn't seem to unset it for this schema: `[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "oyzignasasady647",
    "status": "active",
    "latestVersion": "8.9.8",
    "description": "this is a desc",
    "descriptionShort": "shortDesc",
    "contacts": [
      "\/api\/contacts\/2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ueflasaslqc883",
    "status": "inactive",
    "latestVersion": "0.8.0",
    "description": "desc",
    "descriptionShort": "shortdesc",
    "contacts": [
      "\/api\/contacts\/18"
    ]
  }
]`

Comment: it just ignores it and it is still part of the new array which is returned.

Comment: I still forgot one `$key` instead of `$deleteKey` damn