# indexing JSON in php after removing item

Tags: php, json

How can I re-index a JSON after using `unset($json -> nodes[$data_deleteNode])` to remove an entry? The common method `array_values($json)`, which usally close the gaps doesn´t work. I understand the error message but do not have an idea to solve it.

```
array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

There is a similar thread which refers to the solutions I tried - [PHP json_encode as object after PHP array unset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869129/php-json-encode-as-object-after-php-array-unset/3869219#3869219) the only difference is the JSON.

If I do not perform any sorting, unset() adds an index which cause my JSON to be not readable for other scripts.

[image]

**The affected PHP:**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$data_deleteNode = ($_POST['id']); 

$json = file_get_contents("data2.json");
$json = json_decode($json);

//$data_deleteNode = json_decode($data_deleteNode);

//array_splice($json, 3, 1);

printf("%s\n", json_encode($json));

unset($json -> nodes[$data_deleteNode]);

printf("%s\n", json_encode($json));

$json = array_values($json);
$json = json_encode($json);

file_put_contents("data2.json", $json)

?>
```

**UPDATE**: modified playground which shows the error https://3v4l.org/XPbuo#v730

Comment: `$json` is an object. The array which you modify is `$json->nodes`. You want to run `array_values` on *that*. `$json->nodes = array_values($json->nodes)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can you share sample input for your script, such that others could run it to help you?

Comment: @deceze the error is gone but also the $json -> links values. The data2.json file only stores the nodes now. Thanks for your help so far. We may get into the solution.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't assign the values back to ***`$json->nodes`***, but just directly wrote the return value of `array_values($json->nodes)` to the file…

Comment: I see this as a typo question.  You know how to access the `->nodes` property, you just failed to do it when calling `array_values()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents("data2.json");
$data = json_decode($json);

unset($data->nodes[$data_deleteNode]);

$data->nodes = array_values($data->nodes);
    
$json = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents("data2.json", $json)
```

`$data->nodes` is the array you're modifying and that you need to reset. You do that with:

```
$data->nodes = array_values($data->nodes);
```

Note also that I renamed your variables so `$json` refers to JSON encoded text, and `$data` refers to decoded arrays/objects.